# facing problems at ubuntu partitioning while installing 32-bit Ubuntu alongside a 32-bit windows 8.1

Tags: windows, 32-bit

I'm new to Linux like i have used live Ubuntu but now i'm wishing to install it but the problem is when i approach at partition manager of Ubuntu it only shows my windows 8.1 installation dish and all other space in a single form (i have a 500GB HDD installation disk drive of 8.1 is 40 GB) and all other partitions are not shown.So i need guidance to install Ubuntu in local disk drive G (on my Pc )so that i Don't have to suffer from data loss.Step by step Guide would be nice as i understand nothing about LInux partitioning

Answer (score 0):

You note that all of the space aside from your Win8 installation is in a single form.  Is that form "unallocated space"?  In that case you can choose that space as the space used by the Ubuntu installation.  To do that, follow this link and go to step 4: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

The second part of your question is that you want the ubuntu install on your G:\ drive without losing your data.  Unfortunately, you can't run Linux on an NTFS partition (which your G:\ drive is).  However, you can MOUNT the volume alongside your Linux ext4 filesystem when running your desktop and still access those files.  As long as you only format the unallocated space, you're not going to lose anything on your G:\ drive for Windows.

Hope this helps :3

PS:  If you only have a small amount of unallocated space, you will need to edit the size of your G:\ drive, which is a whole nother beast.  You can do that using gparted http://gparted.org/

Comment: the space which is shown altogether isn't unallocated space as it contains all of my data and g drive is totally empty and i have separated it from my f: drive only for Ubuntu installation

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is very much the same in Linux as it is in Windows. They just use different names for things.

The easiest thing to do is to go back in to Windows, find the Disk Management control panel, and create some free (unallocated) space on your drive for Ubuntu to work with.

If you have removed everything off your Drive G: in windows, go ahead and remove that parition, so that Ubuntu can use it to install. There's a basic guide for disk management operations at [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/).

Comment: the space which is shown altogether isn't unallocated space as it contains all of my data and g drive is totally empty and i have separated it from my f: drive only for Ubuntu installation